# How can I pass parameters in deeplink flutter?

Tags: flutter, deep-linking, android-deep-link, flutter-deep-link

I have setup deeplinking on my flutter application but I'm having trouble in being able to pass and use a parameter. Normally, the deeplink works for a predefined named route, say I press a link https://domain/signup - this will redirect the user to the signup page on my Flutter app. But the issue here is, I'm not able to pass a parameter so that I can make my page more dynamic - say a user presses on a link https://domain/course/:some-id - I want to redirect the user to that specific course page. I believe I have setup the deeplink correctly - well at least to what I have seen from the flutter docs. I'm using named route and I know it says using router is a preferred way to
Here is my AndroidXML file setup

```
<!-- Deep Links -->
<meta-data
                android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled"
                android:value="true"
            />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="scheme"
                    android:host="domain" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- App Links -->
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="domain.com" />
                <data
                android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
```

I have made a custom deeplink handler - and its not working how I wanted it to

```
class DeepLinkHandler {
  static Future<void> initUniLinks(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      // Get the initial deep link
      final initialLink = await getInitialLink();

      // Handle the initial deep link if it exists
      _handleLink(initialLink, context);

      // Listen for incoming deep links
      linkStream.listen((String? link) {
        _handleLink(link, context);
      }, onError: (error) {});
    } catch (error) {
      throw Exception();
    }
  }

  static void _handleLink(String? link, BuildContext context) {
    if (link != null) {
      final Uri deepLink = Uri.parse(link);

      print('deeplink opened was $deepLink');
      // This is where I want to navigate the user to the right page
    }
  }

  static Future<void> openLink(String link) async {
    if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(link))) {
      await launchUrl(Uri.parse(link));
    }
  }
}
```

How can I route to a specific pages with a certain parameter attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem and it was not as hard as I thought (at least not after I got the solution ). Anyways, if you set up a deep-link handler like the one in the above question, you must check which route you want to navigate. The above code setup is correct except it won't work for pages that require arguments or parameters (as there is no place where this is being handled). And you only need to adjust the _handleLink() method.
Here is what I have done to navigate to pages that might require args.

```
class DeepLinkHandler{
...
static void _handleLink(String? link, BuildContext context) {
    if (link != null) {
      final Uri deepLink = Uri.parse(link);
      final String route = deepLink.pathSegments[0];


     // Check for the route by using pathSegment (provided from 
     // uni_links in this case), and once you identify the route 
     // which is getting opened then you can navigate to it using 
     // simple if-statement

      if (route == 'someRouteName') {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => SomePageEquivalentWithYourRouteName(
                arg1: deepLink.pathSegments[1],
                arg2: deepLink.pathSegments[2],
              ),
            ),
          );
      }
  }
}
}
```

Note that this solution requires you to know your URI structure beforehand and the parameters that you will need upon launching that URI. For instance, if you want to load some product from a shared link then you should know how the shared link is structured. If the shared link for eg. is /product/someProductId, then you would do something like

```
 final String route = deepLink.pathSegments[0];

 if(route=='product'){
   //Navigate to the product page and also use .pathSegment[1] to get 
   //the necessary arg
  }
```